# A problem in pulling data on website using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull some weather data by using BS4 from a Chinese weather forecast website:
http://www.weather.com.cn/weather1d/101210301.shtml

Fig 1 and 2 show the content I want to obtain in the Elements of Developer mode.
I want to obtain contents within the div label: `<div class="sk mySkyNull">`

My code is as follows:

```
def getHTMLtext(url):     
    try:         
        kv = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
        r = requests.get(url, headers=kv, timeout = 30)
        r.raise_for_status()              
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding             
        return r.text  
    except:         
        print("访问错误")         
        return" "

url = "http://www.weather.com.cn/weather1d/101210301.shtml"
html = getHTMLtext(url)
soup_test = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
body_test = soup_test.body
data = body_test.find('div', {'class':'con today clearfix'})
data = data.find('div', {'class':'left fl'})
data = data.find('div', {'class':'left-div'})
data = data.find('div', {'id': 'today'})
data = data.find('div', {'class':'t'})
```

When I print the content after
`data.find("div",{"class":"t"})`

it shows
`<div class="sk">`
rather than `<div class="sk mySkyNull">`, (Fig 3), and there is no content in this div label. I don't know the reason.

Thanks for helping!

[Fig 1 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4swFo.png)

[Fig 2 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX75o.png)

[Fig 3 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xruK.png)

I replace
`data.find("div",{"class":"sk mySkyNull"})`
with
`data.find("div",{"class":"sk"})`

I print the content and it shows nothing.

[Fig 4 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8RXo.png)

Comment: [Do not use images to share your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: If the HTML is modified by JavaScript code, you may need something like Selenium to retrieve the final DOM with the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `requests` package only retrieve the source HTML from the page. You can see what is in the source HTML using `ctrl+u` on the page for instance.

The issue is that the content you are trying to get is NOT in the source HTML but is generated each time the page is loaded using JavaScript.

What you want is simulating browser interaction to let the scripts generate the content you want. This can be done using the [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) package or the [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) package.

Comment: Thanks very much！It does work！And also thanks for pointing out that it is inappropriate to share codes using images TAT.